# Mixing GPL v3 and Proprietary library

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, proprietary-code, intellectual-property

My application has two parts GUI and a backend algorithm module. I have used a library under GPLv3 to write my GUI. In the GUI we can create a workflow of different digital signal processing units so I thought to share this GUI to the community under GPL, but I wish to keep my some algorithm modules as proprietary, what are the possible approaches?

[image: Application Interaction diag]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy. Make sure you don't compile your GUI and your algorithms together statically as a single executable. If you do that, you don't have any GPL obligation for your algorithms.

- Run your algorithms as a command-line tool and use inter-process communication in your GUI. This is a very common implementation in computer chess engines.
- Run your algorithms as an internal web server and use internal web connection

Example from computer chess (use process communication):

> https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136434/how-can-i-use-gpl-software-like-stockfish-chess-engine-in-my-unity-game
>
> To do this validly, you must make sure that the free and non-free programs communicate at arms length, that they are not combined in a way that would make them effectively a single program.